DevExtreme nested table won't expand on sorting parent table
I'm using the DevExtreme Nested Data Grid (dx-data-grid) in an Angular application to display hierarchical data. My data structure consists of a parent table, and each row in the parent table can have child rows, which can further have grandchild rows (children of the child rows).

When I initialize the grid, all child and grandchild rows are correctly expanded. However, when I sort the parent table by clicking on a column header, the following issue occurs:
The first-level child rows (directly under the parent rows) remain expanded as expected.
However, the grandchild rows (children of the first-level child rows) unexpectedly collapse.

I have also created a minimal reproducible example on CodeSandbox to better illustrate the issue.
codeSandbox
to reproduce the problem:

expand the row with the ID 2.

Exapand the child row with ID 3.

Now Click on the column name of the first table which includes the row with ID 1 and 2.


Can anyone help me understand why the grandchild rows are collapsing after sorting the parent table, and provide a solution to prevent this behavior? I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions to resolve this issue.

so i think u should try masterdetail in your Datagrid

I am already using master-detail. the second level master detail is getting collapsed when sorting.
